# Logout in UWP with Mobile Apps backend

Tags: c#, azure, windows-store-apps, uwp, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to learn to develop UWP apps.
I followed this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users/) and everything was working fine. But currently it is throwing Unauthorized access error, although it is saying that the credentials are loaded.
So I was wondering if it is possible to logout the user and clear the cached token?

I tried to use this code but it is not working:

```
 private async void ButtonLogout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

        {
            ButtonLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            ButtonSave.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        await App.MobileService.LogoutAsync();

        }
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Azure recently released SDK updates that includes changes in the authentication flow.

Have you already updated to the latest NuGet packages for both the client and server SDKs?
If not, try to update it & then check, it should Work!

Regards,
Kasam

Comment: The only thing I can update is Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform from version 5.0.0 to 5.2.2. When I tried to do that, it completely broke the app (around 150 errors)...